# Cypress.io + Laravel + Github Actions: Running tests in Firefox

Tags: laravel, vue.js, cypress

We have been struggling with this for a while, so was hoping someone out there might be to help us.

What we want:

- Use Cypress for conducting end-to-end tests via Github Actions in a relatively small application using Firefox

Our setup:

- Laravel 7
- Vue w. TypeScript - SPA structure
- Github Actions for CI

The issue we face:

- We are unable to configure an instance with HTTPS / SSL using GitHub actions
- We are able to login to the application (which is a simple PHP page) and see the first pieces of HTML rendered in the view before Firefox blocks everything with the warning: **Secure Connection Failed** (example: https://images.app.goo.gl/93hNyNU7t1WyZpq18)

We have tried endless configurations, commenting out back-end calls, changing the Axios baseURL, changing Laravel settings, but we can't seem to progress.

I hope someone might know a way to get SSL running in a Laravel application on Github actions - since then I think the rest should take care of itself.

Comment: Laravel’s server is a wrapper for the PHP server, which as far as I know does not support HTTPS. You’ll need to find another lightweight server to run it, or see if you can figure out  if you can use ngrok perhaps?